# inconsistent bash behaviour

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, bashrc

I have a windows 10 operating system on which I have installed WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 in it.

It is working fine, but I have some weird behaviour of bash i can't seem to be able to resolve.

If i open bash through start or from within file explorer, bash starts from the windows home directory (c/users/myname) and reads the .bashrc file within.

If i execute bash through command line, powershell or by typing it into my explorer adress bar, it opens through the WSL2 mount and reads the bash.bashrc and .bashrc of which the latter is in my ubuntu home directory.

I want ubuntu to start consistently within my windows environment when called upon from there. What files/configs do I change to be able to change the startup of bash.exe.

Thanks!

Comment: "If i open bash through start or from within file explorer" ... you don't happen to have Git Bash or something installed, do you? I don't recall the behaviour you describe ever being that of WSL's `bash.exe`.

Comment: yes i have git bash installed

Comment: I fixed it, I did not know bash and git-bash were different things.

Answer (score 1):

As you've confirmed that you have Git Bash installed, we can confidently identify the problem.  Edit:  I see in the comments that you figured out how to fix it, but I was almost done writing up the answer, so I'll leave it in place.

Short answer:  Start WSL using the `wsl` command, not `bash`.  That will avoid any confusion between WSL and Git Bash.

Longer answer:

When you type "bash" at the Start menu, it finds the *Windows Application* with "bash" in its name, which is "Git Bash".  When Git for Windows is installed, it adds several programs to the Start Menu (unless, of course, you select *"Don't create a Start Menu folder"*), including, of course Git Bash.  Perhaps older versions of Git for Windows just called it "Bash", but the latest version uses "Git Bash", to avoid confusion.

On the other hand, when you run `bash` at the command-line, it is *not* looking for Start Menu entries; it's looking for executables in your `PATH`.  `bash.exe` is an older, no longer recommended way of starting WSL, of course.  While you *can* still use it, the better option is to switch to the newer `wsl.exe` (or just `wsl`) command.  This will avoid any confusion, plus give you a large number of additional options (see `wsl --help`), such as:

- Backing up your WSL instances
- Starting with another user using `wsl -u root` without needing to `sudo`
- Run a command without starting a shell at all (really by making the command run as the shell) with `wsl --exec` (e.g. `wsl --exec chsh`, `wsl --exec tmux`, etc.)
- Change the WSL version being used
- (Soon, in preview) Mount additional drives, either Windows or virtual
- And much more